# How can Sinon spies register a Vue component method as called when it is called as an event's callback?

Tags: vue.js, sinon, vue-test-utils

I have a method called `testfn` in my vue component that gets called whenever event `testevt` fires. This method contains a call to console.log that clearly shows the method is being called.

When running a test with vue-test-utils, if I create a Sinon spy for the method and call the method directly, the spy correctly detects that the method was called:

```
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {});
var spy = sinon.spy(wrapper.vm, 'testfn');
wrapper.vm.testfn();
expect(spy.called).to.be.true; //(uses the Chai assertion library)
```

This does not throw an error.
However, if I create the same spy, but instead of calling the method directly, I emit the event that calls my method, the method gets called (I can see this because the method contains a call to console.log) but the spy does not register that the method was called. Thus, the following gives an error:

```
const wrapper = mount(MyComponent, {});
var spy = sinon.spy(wrapper.vm, 'testfn');
wrapper.vm.$emit('testevt');
expect(spy.called).to.be.true; //(uses the Chai assertion library)
```

What seems to be happening is that testfn itself is not called, but rather, a clone of it is called. Regardless, how can I use a sinon spy to detect whether testfn, or a clone of it, gets called after I emit the `testevt` event?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying spying like that today with no success so I switched to:

```
const spy = sinon.spy()
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {localVue, methods: {clicked: spy}})
wrapper.get('button').trigger('click')
expect(spy).to.have.been.calledOnce
```

Hopefully someone can find an actual answer - but until then this works.

Comment: ```[vue-test-utils]: overwriting methods via the `methods` property is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. There is no clear migration path for the `methods` property - Vue does not support arbitrarily replacement of methods, nor should VTU. To stub a complex method extract it from the component and test it in isolation. Otherwise, the suggestion is to rethink those tests.
```