# Jasmine spyOn applied to a method. A vue-test-utils async function is awaited. Now, the method is no longer a Jasmine spy. Why?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jasmine, vue-test-utils

I want to test that a Vue component method was invoked when a native event is triggered on it. I use `vue-test-utils`, `karma`, and `jasmine` for testing.

```
  it('should emit enter-key when enter key is pressed in the input field', async () => {
    spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'handleEnterKey').and.callThrough();
    await wrapper.find('input').trigger('keydown.enter');
    expect(wrapper.vm.handleEnterKey).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I've confirmed with `console.log`s, that immediately after I call `spyOn`, the `wrapper.vm.handleEnterKey` method is indeed a spy. However, If I `console.log` `wrapper.vm.handleEnterKey` after the `await`, it is once again the original function. Also, I get the error, `Uncaught (in promise) Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function.`

I've confirmed that the `input` element exists, as well, though it seems I'm also somehow not actually causing the `enter` handler to be invoked. I'm not sure if these two issues are related. The component looks like this:

```
<div>
  <input @keypress.enter.passive="handleEnterKey()">
</div>
```

For reference, here is the `handleEnterKey` method body:

```
handleEnterKey() {
  this.updateQuery();
  this.$emit('enter-key');
},
```

`updateQuery()` is not an async function.

I've been Googling for about 2 hours now and haven't found any indication of why a method should simply stop being a spy after an await. Other stackoverflow answers dealing with "Expected a spy..." seem to mostly revolve around people expecting `spyOn` to return something, or, not understanding that the method name should be passed as the second argument, etc, so don't appear relevant.

I tried the two solutions offered in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859759), and though they seemed promising, neither caused any different effect. The error remained identical.

Nor did the jasmine version of [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61275437) work.

**Why is my method no longer a jasmine spy, after a promise is resolved?**

Answer (score 0):

My coworker pulled my code it worked. The test passed. The function (spy) was invoked.

So, I restarted my computer.

Now, it works.

I wish I could say more about why it just wasn't working before.